# Riddle - He who holds the answer may enter

Tags: riddle, english

Here's a riddle I used in a game some time ago. Not the best riddle ever, but we had fun solving it.

It was written on a translucent door, on the frame of which was written "He who holds the answer may enter". What's the riddle about and what would your action be?

```
We're quite the couple, you and I
If you let me live, I'll surely die

If you kill me to live another night
I'll be there next evening, at your side

I won't keep you warm, I'll give you that
And I am most cold when I wear my hat

Whenever I cry you just leave me be
while your tears are like poison to me

I see the pain in your eyes, whenever we touch
I shiver when you speak or shush

If we're too passionate you'll surely die
We're quite the couple, you and I
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The item spoken of in the riddle is

> a candle.

```
We're quite the couple, you and I
If you let me live, I'll surely die
```

> Leave the candle burning, it will be consumed.

```
If you kill me to live another night
I'll be there next evening, at your side
```

> snuff out the candle flame and you will be able to re-use the candle the next night.

```
I won't keep you warm, I'll give you that
And I am most cold when I wear my hat
```

> Candle flames are good for (a little) light, not for keeping things warm; if you put a "hat" (a candle-snuffer) on a candle, it goes out and doesn't provide any warmth at all.

```
Whenever I cry you just leave me be
while your tears are like poison to me
```

> The candle's "tears" are the wax runoff, which we don't do anything about; but our tears would put out the candle-flame.

```
I see the pain in your eyes, whenever we touch
I shiver when you speak or shush
```

> it hurts us to touch the candleflame, and the flame flickers from the air-currents of our breathing or speaking.

```
If we're too passionate you'll surely die
We're quite the couple, you and I
```

> Let the flame get too big/too close, you're in for a world of hurt.

So, my action would be

> stepping through the doorframe while holding a lit candle.

Comment: 100% correct and well explained!