# Puzzle and riddle in one - what am I?

Tags: riddle, english, enigmatic-puzzle

These letters are carved in groups on a wall as shown. You know an answer is needed to continue your journey, but no other instructions are apparent.

```
to   na   ts   ta   yw   te   og   er   sv   ii   gi   rr
ht   gr   ow   iv   hh   oo   uo   rt   ie   aa   iv   ue
ew   sd   wh   oe   ia   fp   no   gh   tr   pm   ve   ne
sa   ew   ee   ns   st   il   dd   rs   aw   pw   eg   da


ch   ou   ol   at   ot   ch   ta   eh   ga   ot   mo   re
re   ft   ol   yo   uo   oe   iv   aa   im   ue   an   sa
ec   hn   rm   st   no   nn   oe   rt   vh   nr   nl   tc
ar   ee   le   pe   dd   dp   ns   ai   ie   db   py   st
```

What would your answer be?

(Another puzzle/riddle I used in a game. Seeing as how fast [my previous riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8352/riddle-he-who-holds-the-answer-may-enter) was solved, I'm not giving any more hints right away :) )

Comment: Nice puzzle Taco! Looking forward to the next one :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stealing the plaintext from [Uri Zarfaty's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10618/5373), my guess is:

> A wishing well.
>  
>  The well is a tower-like hole in the ground, where earth used to be, containing water but not waves. Lines 3-4 refer to the other meaning of the word "well". People "pay" the well by throwing loose change into it, and verbalizing their wishes.

Comment: After reading Uri Zarfaty's decoded riddle, your answer was my immedate thought for the puzzle answer.

Comment: Yup, that's it! Although line 3 was intended to be interpreted differently, did you mean lines 4-5?

Answer (score 15):

I think I've figured out the riddle, but unfortunately I suck at riddles :-(

> Reading from top to bottom rather than left to right (i.e. starting with 'thes'), it's clear that many of the four-letter fragments contain common English ngrams ('tion', 'ound', etc). Trying to match some up, I noticed that TOFI is the only thing that can go before RSTS, while its neighbor EOPL (presumably part of PEOPLE) could only go before EARA or EACT (the neighbor of RSTS). I assumed it was the latter and tried to match up *pairs* of four letters, gradually creating the following text: 
>
>  `iapp eara towe rund ergr ound`
>  `iamw hati swhe reea rths tood`
>  
>  `givi ngse cond tofi rsts ound`
>  `amhe ardw henp eopl eact good`
>  
>  `give thes ound ofhe sita tion`
>  `iveg otwa terb utne verw aves`
>  
>  `manp aysp oorl yhis crea tion`
>  `only tote llme what hecr aves`
>
>  which, reformatted, gives the following riddle:
>  *I appear a tower underground*
>  *I am what is where earth stood*
>  *Giving second to first sound*
>  *Am heard when people act good*
>  *Give the sound of hesitation*
>  *I've got water but never waves*
>  *Man pays poorly his creation*
>  *Only to tell me what he craves*

Unless I suffer an atypical stroke of inspiration, I'll leave the actual answer to someone else...

Comment: Well I cannot accept this as the answer, I guess, but you got the puzzle part nailed! Funny how you got the actual order as intended, although some permutations of it would be just as valid.

Comment: @TacoV: I did wonder about the order, but this one seemed most natural. Certainly it made sense to start with the "I appear" lines.

Answer (score 2):

Now that [Uri Zarfaty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10618/5373) has solved the cryptograms, I can have a go at the riddle. Here it is again:

> I appear a tower underground 
> I am what is where earth stood 
> Giving second to first sound 
> Am heard when people act good 
> Give the sound of hesitation 
> I've got water but never waves 
> Man pays poorly his creation 
> Only to tell me what he craves

I think the answer could be

> an underground water tank.

This is like a water tower but underground (hence line 1); earth has been displaced to make room for it there (hence line 2); it sounds a bit like "thanks" with the second letter removed (hence lines 3 and 4); it contains water (hence line 6), which is necessary for people to live (hence line 8). Line 5 sounds like a reference to the word "er" (Harry Potter's "spider" riddle, anyone?), and I'm not entirely sure about line 7.

Comment: Nope, but close. I don't really understand your explanation of line 5 - guess I'll have to get out the books to check your reference :)

Comment: @TacoV Goblet of Fire, third task ;-)